# Am I producing a memory leak? C++, Pointers New/delete

Tags: c++

I'm not really sure about the following:

I'm creating a pointer to a Gui_Modal_Window object in my header file:

**editor.h**

```
 Gui_Modal_Window* gui_modal_window_map_saved;
```

And somewhere in the body of my cpp-file, I'm creating a new Modal Window (when the user clicks on a specific button..)

**editor.cpp**

```
gui_modal_window_map_saved = new Gui_Modal_Window("Map saved", "The map has been saved.");
```

For deleting the Modal window again, I use the following method:

```
void Gui::delete_element(Gui* elem) {
    delete elem;
    elem = NULL;
}
```

I'm wondering if I'm creating a memory leak here, because my Visual Studio snapshots show, that the allocations won't reduce to what they were before creating the Modal Window..

(see the attached image, the screenshots show the allocations when starting the programm (1), after creating a Modal Window (2) and then after deleting that Modal Window again (3)).

[image: Allocations]

### Edit 2

I followed jaggedSpire's advice and replaced all the pieces with new/delete raw-pointers with smart pointers. And I think that it definitely changed something. Look at the new attached image - the amount of allocations before creating and after closing the gui shows, that the amount of new allocations is the same as the amount of removed allocations. I'm no profiling expert - am I somehow correct or is this just a total random thing?

[image: Allocation with smart pointers]

### Edit

Okay, so here is some code from the project. I've stripped out some elements that I think are not necessary, but correct me if I'm wrong.

**Gui.h**

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include "Gui_.h"

class Gui {

private:
    static std::vector<Gui*> g_elements;            // static list of gui elements
    static std::vector<g_event> g_events;           // static map of gui events

protected:
    std::vector<Gui*> siblings;                     // holds each element's siblings

    int id;

    void static add(Gui* element);
    void static remove(Gui* element);
    void virtual calculate_size() { return; };

public:
    Gui();
    virtual ~Gui();

    void show();
    void hide();

    void add_element(Gui* elem);
    void virtual update_element() { return; }
    int get_element_count();

    void add_event(int event_id, Gui &elem);
    g_event get_event();

    void update();
    void virtual render();

};
```

**Gui.cpp**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "settings.h"
#include "Input.h"
#include "Gui.h"


std::vector<Gui*> Gui::g_elements;
std::vector<g_event> Gui::g_events;

//
Gui::Gui() {
    printf("new gui");
    // Some graphic engine inits..
}


//
Gui::~Gui() {

}


//
int Gui::get_element_count() {
    return g_elements.size();
}


//
void Gui::update() {

    // Update each element and it's siblings
    if (g_elements.size() > 0) {
        for (auto& g : g_elements) {
            g->update_element();
        }
    }

}


//
void Gui::render() {

    if (g_elements.size() > 0) {
        for (auto& g : g_elements) {
            g->render();
        }
    }

}


//
void Gui::add(Gui* element) {
    g_elements.push_back(element);
}


//
void Gui::remove(Gui* element) {

    int i;
    for(i=0;i<g_elements.size();i++) {

        if (g_elements[i] == element) {
            g_elements.erase(g_elements.begin() + i);
        }
    }

}


//
void Gui::add_element(Gui* element) {

    siblings.push_back(element);
    // some assignments to the sibling..

    printf("\nAssigned an element to another element\n");

}


//
void Gui::add_event(int event_id, Gui& elem) {

    g_events.push_back({ event_id, &elem });

}


//
g_event Gui::get_event() {

    if (g_events.size() > 0) {
        g_event g = g_events.back();
        g_events.pop_back();
        return g;
    }
    else
        return {};
}
```

**Gui_Modal_Window.h**

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include "Gui.h"

class Gui_Modal_Window : public Gui {

protected:
    std::string caption;
    std::string message;
    void virtual calculate_size() override;

public:
    Gui_Modal_Window(std::string caption, std::string message);
    ~Gui_Modal_Window() override;

    void update_element() override;
    void render() override;

};
```

**Gui_Modal_Window.cpp**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "settings.h"
#include "Input.h"
#include "Gui.h"
#include "Gui_Modal_Window.h"


//
Gui_Modal_Window::~Gui_Modal_Window() {

    // Delete all siblings (adopt parent's values)
    if (siblings.size() > 0) {
        for (auto &s : siblings) {
            delete s;
        }
    }

    remove(this);

    printf("deleted a gui modal");

}


//
Gui_Modal_Window::Gui_Modal_Window(std::string caption, std::string message) {
    add(this);

    this->caption = caption;
    this->message = message;

    this->calculate_size();

    //this->x = (screen_width / 2) - (this->w / 2);
    //this->y = (screen_height / 2) - (this->h / 2);

    this->id = get_element_count() + 1;

    printf("\nNEW MODAL WINDOW\n");

}


//
void Gui_Modal_Window::calculate_size() {

    // size calculations


}


//
void Gui_Modal_Window::update_element() {

    calculate_size();

    // Update all siblings (adopt parent's values)
    for (auto &s : siblings) {
        s->x = x + s->old_x;
        s->y = y + s->old_y;
        s->hidden = hidden;
    }

}


//
void Gui_Modal_Window::render() {

    if (!hidden) {
        // draw the gui element..
    }

}
```

**Editor.h** (snippet)

```
#pragma once
#include "settings.h"
#include "Layer.h"
#include "EditorMenu.h"

class EditorMenu;
class Map;
class Gui;
class Gui_Modal_Window;
class Gui_Button;

class Editor {

friend class Map;

private: 
    Gui* gui;
    Gui_Modal_Window* gui_modal_window_map_saved;
Gui_Button* gui_modal_window_map_saved_button;
```

// ....

**Editor.cpp** (snippet)

```
Editor::Editor() {

    //this->map = new Map();
    //this->cmd = new Command();
    //this->menu = new EditorMenu(this, cmd);
this->gui = new Gui();
```

//...

**Creating the Window**

```
// Saves the current map into a XML file
void Editor::tool_map_save() {

    map->save(0, *this);

    this->gui_modal_window_map_saved = new Gui_Modal_Window("Map saved", "The map has been saved."
        "This is also a very long text, to see"
        "if this gets calculated good enough!"
    );
    this->gui_modal_window_map_saved_button = new Gui_Button("Okay!", 20, 70, 200, 40, BUTTON_CONFIRM);
    gui_modal_window_map_saved->add_element(gui_modal_window_map_saved_button);
    gui_modal_window_map_saved_button->add_element(gui_modal_window_map_saved);

    gui_modal_window_map_saved->show();

}
```

**and in the Editor::update() - method:**

```
// Gui events
    g_event g_ev = gui->get_event();

    if (g_ev.event_id == EVENT_CLICKED && g_ev.element == gui_modal_window_map_saved_button) {
        delete gui_modal_window_map_saved;
    }
```

Comment: protip: instead of using new and delete, try out smart pointers.

Comment: Create and delete again and see if it keeps going up

Comment: It increases all the time @user3853544

Comment: `elem = NULL;` is setting the function's local copy of the pointer to `NULL`, after which the function finishes and that copy is destroyed, making the assignment completely pointless.

Comment: Is it supposed to do that?

Comment: Yeah, I tried it, but I'm somehow new to C++ and didn't know where to start. Will I have to create the unique_ptr in my header file? @jaggedSpire

Comment: from where is `delete_element` called? did you prove using a debugger that it gets actually executed? any other resources inside the lifecycle of a `Gui_Modal_Window` that might not be released?

Comment: @user3853544: No, I thought that it should return to the original number of allocations after destroying..

Comment: @dlatikay: From the editor.cpp, inside my update-loop.. I've done a quick printf-debug and it seems to be executed, yes.

Comment: It's hard to say exactly which steps to take to convert to a unique_ptr here, since there's not a whole lot of context for your code, but replacing `T*` with `std::unique_ptr<T>`, `new T(args...)` with `std::make_unique<T>(args...)`, and `delete t;` with a scope exit is a start.

Comment: Create/delete it like 20 times and see if you get a proportional spike.  From the looks of it this should produce no leak.  Is 'Gui_Modal_Window' written by you?

Comment: What kind of `Gui` is this? Who wrote it? And who wrote `Gui_Modal_Window`?  If you wrote them, then there is a lot more explaining that you are going to have to do, and a lot more code that you are going to have to show, before we can guess what's wrong.

Comment: Random guess - is destructor of class `Gui` virtual?

Comment: You allocate space for type of Gui_Modal_Window whereas deletion takes place for elem pointer that is type of Gui. That might be the reason. They are different types of pointers. Try deleting Gui_Modal_Window itself to see if it would make a difference just to test.

Comment: *my Visual Studio snapshots show, that the allocations won't reduce to what they were before creating the Modal Window* That is not necessarily a sign of memory leaks. It's possible for the program not to release the memory to the OS immediately after you called `delete` on a pointer.

Comment: @RSahu, I am yet to see an implementation which **does** return memory to OS after it has being freed

Comment: @SergeyA, I meant to say *immediately after*.

Comment: @SergeyA: Yes, the destructor of Gui is virtual. You seem to know, what's wrong with that?
I've placed some debug printfs in my Gui element destructors and they all seem to be fired.

Comment: When people ask you things in the comments, it is best to answer them.  All of them.

Comment: @MikeNakis: Yes, I know. I had no time left that day.. Regarding your question, I'm writing that Gui class, well, it is more a simple graphical wrapper for some windows and buttons - it is an gui for a game,  so there is no need for higher logic or stuff like that. I know that there are a lot of existing guis, but this whole project has also a kind of educational thought. I'm not sure if showing the whole source will help, as there is really nothing spectecular going on in there, but I could edit my question with some snippets..

Comment: what if the user presses the create button multiple times?

Comment: @Raindrop7: Then multiple instances of my Gui elements are created. Let me double check this regarding the removing of them.

Comment: I've updated the question with some real code.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with how you allocate your `Gui_Modal_Window` and how you free it.  The problem is that your `Gui_Modal_Window` needs to have a destructor, and this destructor must release all of the resources of the underlying GUI that it wraps.  (Which we know nothing about because you have told us absolutely nothing about them, as if they were irrelevant to the question.)

Comment: Updated the question.

Comment: So, does your code have a comment saying "// Some graphic engine inits.." in it, or does it actually have some graphic engine inits in it?

Comment: It actually has some graphic engine inits in it :)  Everything that is commented out with //... is done for keeping things more readable.