# Making sense of Microsoft's Memory Leak Detection output

Tags: c++, visual-studio, memory-leaks

Sorry for the bad title, but I'm just curious what exactly a memory leak is respectively how I really can say that I've done some bad things in my program.

I've run the Memory Leak Test in Visual Studio (_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks()) and it outputs a huge list of detected leaks (just showing a small portion):

```
{1640} normal block at 0x081C2AB0, 4 bytes long.
 Data: <;   > 3B 00 00 00 
{789} normal block at 0x08B792E8, 12 bytes long.
 Data: <            > 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
{788} normal block at 0x027E62D8, 32 bytes long.
 Data: <         L   L  > 20 A8 FE 07 A0 A0 17 08 E4 4C F3 07 D8 4C F3 07 
{787} normal block at 0x027E6328, 32 bytes long.
 Data: <layer03 - Object> 6C 61 79 65 72 30 33 20 2D 20 4F 62 6A 65 63 74 
{786} normal block at 0x08B79748, 8 bytes long.
 Data: <`N      > 60 4E F3 07 00 00 00 00
```

I can't really figure out, what exactly I've done wrong. I've followed the tipps from [another question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41813753/am-i-producing-a-memory-leak-c-pointers-new-delete/41828044) and replaced all `new/delete` things with **smart pointers** (or at least I think I did).

The reason I ask is, because I've encountered an increase in my memory size and heap size while running my program and I'm not sure, if it is some serious problem or just some kind of basic behaviour.

Take my (self written) gui for example:

```
std::shared_ptr<Gui_Button> gui_modal_window_map_saved_button;
```

And I now call it with:

```
gui_modal_window_map_saved_button.reset(new Gui_Button(res_handler, "Select", 20, 345, 70, 40, BUTTON_CONFIRM));
```

which has been told to be memory safe. Now, there's something that I am not really sure about - how do I safely delete the button now? I know, there's nothing like delete with smart pointers, but I think of deleting in the way of removing the button when it is not needed any longer, i.e. after the corresponding window has been closed.

At the moment I'm "deleting" my button with `reset()`

```
if (g_ev.event_id == EVENT_CLICKED && g_ev.element == gui_modal_window_map_saved_button.get()) {
        gui_modal_window_map_saved.reset();
        gui_modal_window_map_saved_button.reset();
    }
```

I thought that this was okay, but why is my memory size increasing (and not decreasing again) everytime a "new" button is created?

**Coming back to the original question**

I get these dumps of memory leaks by Visual Studio, but I really can't figure out how to use this information. What exactly causes a memory leak? I'm now using only "normal" pointers where I need to pass something to another class i.e., and replaced all `new/deletes` with smart pointers. I really can't show my code, because it is about 3000 lines so far..

So, what exactly causes memory leaks and how doI use the informations provided by VS?

Comment: This a general question?

Comment: Memory leaks are not about hardware, unless you leave your laptop in the rain...

Comment: Grey area. I would say memory leak is a general question.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak and more https://www.google.de/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=what+is+a+memory+leak+c%2B%2B

Comment: *"I'm now using only "normal" pointers where I need to pass something to another class"* - sounds like you should use references instead.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has provided detailed information on how to utilize the data you are seeing: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x98tx3cf.aspx

It is possible to use the allocation number to break in your code at the point when the allocation is made. In the following line from the debug output:

`{789} normal block at 0x08B792E8, 12 bytes long.`

789 is the allocation number. You mention that memory use is growing. This does not necessarily speak to a growing leak unless there is a corresponding increase of leak messages when you do longer sessions.

Another thing to consider is that the leak is occurring within your class. If there are any elements allocated within your object that are not properly disposed of, no smart pointer is going to save you.

Comment: "If you don't see an increase in leak records at the end of your run, you do not have a growing leak." - could you explain that any further? How would I measure the records at the end of the run?

Comment: Count them. If there are more than you can quickly count, then it doesn't matter if it is growing. You have enough of a problem as it is.

Answer (score 0):

C++ differs from many newer languages in that it doesn't have a so called garbage collector. You allocate (claim) memory with `new` and explicitly deallocate (release) it again with `delete`.

If you forget the `delete`, the memory will only be freed by the operating system after your program exists.

To balance the use of `new` with the use of `delete`, if possible only allocate memory in constructors and deallocate it in (virtual) destructors. In this way, if an object owning a piece of heap memory (memory that's allocated with `new`) goes out of scope (e.g. a local variable when leaving a function), the memory will automatically be released.

By the way, allocating and deallocating memory in this way is one of the things that gives C++ its versatility and speed. So it's an asset rather than something to be avoided. But it requires careful use.

Comment: Yes, that is something that I've learned. But, if I don't explicitly call new, then I shouldn't get any problems, shouldn't I?

Comment: Indeed, you shouldn't.

Comment: In some other answer I read that it is possible that I call _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks(); at an inappropriate place. Currently, I've placed it right before the end of my program (before return 0;)

Comment: Maybe you can diagnose problems that way, but if your design requires it, you've got a problem. Best stick to the constructor / destructor rule, often worded as 'construction is resource allocation', 'destruction is resource dealloction'. Resources by the way, can also be open files, semaphores and things like that.

Comment: Nowdays the smart pointers are the talk of the town. `new` and `delete` not so much.

Comment: JavaScript is also the talk of the town. Still I like the simple, clear, fast control that new and delete give me.

Comment: **A garbage collector does not prevent memory leaks.** My favourite example is that of Java GUI components which fail to unregister themselves at some listener collection. This causes all the graphics and other resources referenced by the GUI component not be garbage-collected, because they can still be reached. I've seen this problem in real production code, in Android applications.

Comment: @JacquesdeHooge: Typically, it is that bad, because standard library containers and `std::unique_ptr` are enough for the vast majority of use cases, but there are a few exceptions, like when an object in an event-handling system wants to delete itself in the destructor. Observing raw pointers are another exception.